# Disabling two factor authenticator In MeteorJS

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to disable the 2fa authenticator of a user in MeteorJS according to this https://docs.meteor.com/packages/accounts-2fa.html

In the documents of the MeteorJS they have a function called `Accounts.disableUser2fa([callback])`

However this function can only be used if a user is logged in

I use `Accounts.logWithPassword` if user does not have 2fa and `Accounts.loginWithPasswordAnd2faCode` if user has 2fa however in both ways if err is called back then the user is never signed in and so I cannot use `Accounts.disableUser2fa` function
and the user will be stuck with out signing in

Is there anyway to manipulate this so I can disable a user 2fa when he wants to reset

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the `users` collection record, remove the `services.twoFactorAuthentication` property.

Comment: Also, it is not possible to use Meteor.user() as it is available only when user is logged in